# Tidy evaluation when renaming columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyeval

I'm trying to dynamically rename a single column in a dataframe using `rename()` with the *tidy evaluation* syntax released in [`dplyr` v0.7.0](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/13/dplyr-0-7-0/).

From the `?rename` help page, I found the following example to rename 2 columns.

```
library(dplyr)

vars <- c(var1 = "cyl", var2 ="am")
rename(mtcars, !!vars) %>% head(1)

>           mpg var1 disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs var2 gear carb
> Mazda RX4  21    6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0    1    4    4
```

However, I've noticed I cannot use this same syntax to rename a single column.

```
vars <- c(var1 = "cyl")
rename(mtcars, !!vars) %>% head(1)

> Error: All arguments must be named
```

Yet, when I rename **the same column twice**, it works.

```
vars <- c(var1 = "cyl", var1 = "cyl")
rename(mtcars, !!vars) %>% head(1)

>           mpg var1 disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> Mazda RX4  21    6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

Why is this happening? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Upstream issue: github.com/tidyverse/tidyselect/issues/77

Answer (score 3):

Use the `!!!` for evaluation

```
rename(mtcars, !!!vars) %>% 
     head(1)
#          mpg var1 disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4  21    6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the `!!` evaluation produces an error when only 1 column is specified?

Comment: @Megatron It is a bit surprising that `!!` works with more than 1 element.  If you change it to a `list`, then the first option wouldn't work.  Internally, could be that with the vector of length 1, the name gets stripped off

Comment: Any idea where I can find the new tidy eval formal spec? I've never seen the `!!!` operator before. Also the >1 element renaming is straight from the help page. I think the vector/list issue must be a bug.

Comment: This looks like a bug, I have filed an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyselect/issues/77