# Turning dplyr code into function that accepts columns as arguments

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval

I've been fighting trying to understand `tidyeval` and the use of `quo`, `quos`, `sym`, `!!`, `!!!` and the like. I made some attempts, but couldn't generalize my code so it accepts a vector of columns and applies text processing to those columns on a dataframe. My dataframe looks like this:

```
ocupation      tasks                 id 
 Sink Cleaner   Cleaning the sink    1
 Lion petter    Pet the lions        2
```

And my code looks like this:

```
stopwords_regex = paste(tm::stopwords('en'), collapse = '\\b|\\b')
stopwords_regex = glue('\\b{stopwords_regex}\\b')


df = df %>% mutate(ocupation_proc = ocupation %>% tolower() %>% 
                     stringi::stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII") %>% 
                     str_remove_all(stopwords_regex) %>% 
                     str_remove_all("[[:punct:]]") %>%  
                     str_squish(),
                   tasks_proc = tasks %>% tolower() %>% 
                     stringi::stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII") %>% 
                     str_remove_all(stopwords_regex) %>%
                     str_remove_all("[[:punct:]]") %>% 
                     str_squish())
```

Which brings something like this:

```
ocupation      tasks               id    ocupation_proc  tasks_proc
Sink Cleaner   Cleaning the sink   1     sink cleaner   cleaning sink
Lion petter    Pet the lions       2      lion petter    pet lions
```

I'd like to turn this into a function `process_text_columns(df, columns_list, new_col_names)` Where in this case `df=df`, `columns_list=c('ocupation', 'tasks')` and `new_col_names=c('ocupation_proc', 'tasks_proc')`, (`new_col_names` might not even be necessary if I can do something like `glue({colname}_proc)` to name the new columns). From what I've gathered I'd need to use `across`, `sym`, `quos` and maybe `!!!` to generalize the function but anything I've tried has failed. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: They should be enough to make a reproducible example. The only thing I need is a function that can take n column names as arguments and processes text for those, so later I may directly use it in another dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you as expected? The "curly curly" operator introduced to rlang 0.4 in June 2019 helps simplify the ["quote-and-unquote into a single interpolation step."](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/)

```
clean_steps <- function(a_column) {
  a_column %>%
    tolower() %>% 
    stringi::stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII") %>% 
    str_remove_all(stopwords_regex) %>%
    str_remove_all("[[:punct:]]") %>% 
    str_squish()
}

my_great_function <- function(df, columns_list, new_col_names) {
  mutate(df, across( {{columns_list}}, ~clean_steps(.x))) %>%
    rename( !!new_col_names )
}

my_great_function(df, 
                  c(ocupation, tasks), 
                  c(ocu = "ocupation", tas = "tasks"))
```

Output

```
           ocu           tas id
1 sink cleaner cleaning sink  1
2  lion petter     pet lions  2
```

EDIT: To keep unprocessed columns and add processed with new names, easiest would be to use the `.names` argument of `across`:

```
my_great_function <- function(df, columns_list, new_col_names) {
  mutate(df, across( {{columns_list}}, ~clean_steps(.x), .names = "{.col}_proc"))
}

my_great_function(df, c(ocupation, tasks))


     ocupation             tasks id ocupation_proc    tasks_proc
1 Sink Cleaner Cleaning the sink  1   sink cleaner cleaning sink
2  Lion petter     Pet the lions  2    lion petter     pet lions
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you very much! I have many questions, but first of all I wanted to ask you if it's easily possible to create these columns as new columns with different names using this code? I guess something in `mutate` can be done to do so

Comment: updated with approach from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482185/tidy-evaluation-when-renaming-columns-in-dplyr

Comment: Thanks again! One of my other questions was about "curly curly" which is a great tool to know about, thanks for providing a source too. My last question is about `~clean_steps(.x)`, what does the tilde operator mean in this case? Also, I assume `.x` tells R to apply the function on each element of the list, right?

Comment: Check out the help for `?dplyr::across` -- it specifies a few ways to refer to the functions you want to use. The tilde is borrowing syntax from another `tidyverse` package, `purrr`, where as you said the `.x` is the placeholder for the input to the function.

Comment: I noticed the problem was the desired output I posted, it was wrong. I wanted to create new columns and preserve the old ones, which is what I edited in now. As of now I could do that by pre-creating a copy of the columns before the function runs and then applying the code which would give me the modified version, but this doesn't seem very straight-forward. Do you have any ideas to better achieve this same thing? Thanks !

Comment: See edit: `across` has a `.names` argument where we can manipulate the column names, e.g. by adding a suffix `_proc`

Comment: Thanks for all the help Jon, very much appreciated!